# jQuery: Do function if content matches regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to run a jQuery function on every `<p>` element whose inner content matches the regex expression **`/^\s*o\s+/m`**.  I have no idea how to do it.  Suggestions, please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use jQuery filter():**

```
$('p').filter(function() {

    return (/^\s*o\s+/).test($(this).text()); // return every match as jQuery obj

}).css('background-color', 'red'); // <--example, do your stuff here.
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j34z5/)
- [.filter()<sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: I'd use .test instead of .match in this case

Answer (score 4):

```
$("p").each(function () {
   if (/^\s*o\s+/m.test(this.innerHTML)) {
        // what to do here.
   }
})
```

This is how you do it, but you should work on the regex, cause i dont really know what it does.